# OpeanAL buffers

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

According to my understanding of OpenAL objects, a OpenAL Buffer belongs to a device, and not a context. If I want to create a buffer I do so with alGenBuffers(), but I am not sure which device this buffer will be created on. How do I choose which device to create the buffer on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OpenAL Buffer belongs to a device, and not a context

When you create a buffer using `alGenBuffers()`, then the buffer is indeed created on a specific device. In short, when calling `alGenBuffers()` it gets the active context's device. The buffer is then created on that device.

> How do I choose which device to create the buffer on?

Thus, you need to get another device and create a new context with that device:

```
ALCdevice *device = alcOpenDevice(...);
ALCcontext *context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
```

Then make this new context the current active context:

```
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
```

Now any `alGenBuffers()`, `alBufferData()`, etc. is applied to that active context and in turn applied to the active context's device.